# How to form number as nine digit number

Tags: ruby, string

Input: `1234567`

I want the output to be nine digit as below:

Output: `001/234/567`

How do I do it in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1234567.to_s.rjust(9, '0').scan(/.../).join('/')
# => "001/234/567"
```

Answer (score 0):

d = '1234567'

d.scan(/.{3}|.+/).join("/")

Explanation:

Scan groups all matches of the regexp into an array. The .{3} matches any 3 characters. If there are characters left at the end of the string, they will be matched by the .+. Join the array with your string

Comment: It works perfectly fine, the input just has to be declared as a string value, then it will work